# Pending Intent Fires Immediately

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am trying to make an app that allows the user to enter two times using two TimePickers and the phone will set to silent between these times. I am using PendingIntent and AlarmManager to trigger the BroadcastReceiver at the times the user chooses.
At the moment, it is setting the phone on and off silent immediately when the user clicks the save button. My "alarm scheduled" toast then appears and my "broadcast received" appears twice but it doesn't do anything after that.

Here is my main activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

AlarmManager alarm;
TimePicker timePickerStart;
TimePicker timePickerEnd;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    timePickerStart = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePickerStart);
    timePickerStart.setIs24HourView(true);
    timePickerEnd = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePickerEnd);
    timePickerEnd.setIs24HourView(true);

}


//method is called when save button is clicked
public void setAlarm(View view) {
    Calendar calendarStart;
    Calendar calendarEnd;

    calendarStart = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendarEnd = Calendar.getInstance();


    //Set calendars to the times in both TimePickers
    calendarStart.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, timePickerStart.getCurrentHour(), timePickerStart.getCurrentMinute());
    long startTimeMillis = calendarStart.getTimeInMillis();

    calendarEnd.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, timePickerEnd.getCurrentHour(), timePickerEnd.getCurrentMinute());
    long endTimeMillis = calendarEnd.getTimeInMillis();



    //create an intent and set the class that will be triggered by the intent
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Receiver.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = null;
    pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 123, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    //create alarm manager
    alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    //set alarms to go off at the time specified by the timePickers
    alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendarStart.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
    alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendarEnd.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);

    //Toast for feedback
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Scheduled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Here is my BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

AudioManager audioManager;
int modeNum;


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    //toast for feedback
    Toast.makeText(context, "Broadcast Received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    modeNum = audioManager.getRingerMode();
    if (modeNum == 0) {
        audioManager.setRingerMode(2);
    } else {
        audioManager.setRingerMode(0);
    }
}
```

}

This is my Manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".Receiver"></receiver>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple problems.

First, you are trying to create two alarms with the same `PendingIntent`. That will not work. Your second alarm request will cancel the first one. You need *distinct* `PendingIntent` objects, which means either substantially different `Intent` objects wrapped by the `PendingIntent` objects, or use two different values where you have `123`.

Second, your `set()` calls on `Calendar` are incorrect. For example, in both places, your first parameter is supposed to be year. You are passing `Calendar.YEAR`, which is `1`, not `2015`.